# Parallel Structure: Can you improve this sentence?

Tags: parallelism

I'm currently writing something and this sentence seems pretty ugly. How can this sentence be improved? Any help is appreciated.

"Day after day, you wake up early to make sure we get to school, bring us any homework or lost material that we constantly forget at home, come to all our school plays, winter concerts, sports events, and competitions, and are altogether the center of the Academy community."

Comment: "*any* homework ....that we *constantly* forget"  is a little jarring. "*the* homework" or "*our* homework" would work better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking writing style advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Day in and day out, you get up early to get us off to school, bring us homework or other stuff we are constantly forgetting at home, *and* attend all our school plays, concerts, sports' events, and competitions:  you are truly at the heart of the [name of school] community."

Comment: +1 for starting a new independent clause with "you are".

Comment: Can "forget" be used in progressive tense in this case as *"we are constantly forgetting at home"*? shouldn't it be 'we keep forgetting'?